# Why adding a Contact by Intent is not working?

Tags: android

I have added the `permission` to write contacts in `Manifest.xml`, but the contact is not being saving.

```
final EditText name = findViewById(R.id.name);
final EditText number = findViewById(R.id.number);

Button add = findViewById(R.id.add);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        intent
          .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,number.getText())
          .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
          .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,name.getText());

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In the `emulator`, when I click add button, the name and phone number won't get in place, every fields is blank. How to solve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider

Comment: try converting the EditText values to String like name.getText().toString()

Comment: @deepakkumar That worked man Thanks Alot Thanks Alot for your help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

variables `name` and `number` are probably not defined in that scope ...

```
Button add = findViewById(R.id.add);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    final EditText name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText number = findViewById(R.id.number);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        intent    
        .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, number.getText().toString())
    .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
        .putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually what do you mean by name and number are not defined in that scope didn't got your point. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @FawadLang just updated that; so that it is known within the scope of the listener.